# Commitment to a polynomial

Tags: protocol-design, commitments

$A(x) \bmod B(x) = C(x)$ and $A(x) \bmod D(x) = E(x)$:

A dealer knows $A(x)$ polynomial, which is a secret. He distributes $C(x)$ and $E(x)$ privately to $X$ and $Y$, respectively. $B(x)$ and $D(x)$ are public. $X$ and $Y$ want to know that $C(x)$ and $E(x)$ is the result of $A(x) \bmod B(x)$ and $A(x) \bmod D(x)$, respectively, without getting to know $A(x)$.

Is it possible to the dealer to commmit to $A(x)$ to prove that this is the polynomial being used in both expressions?

Comment: A dealer owns A(x), which is secret. He distributes C(x) and E(x) privately to X and Y, respectively. B(x) and D(x) are public. X and Y want to know that C(x) and E(x) is the result of A(x) mod B(x) and A(x) mod D(x), respectively, without getting to know A(x).

Comment: What ring/field are the polynomials defined over?  $\mathbb{Z}$?  $GF(p)$ for some prime $p$?  Can we pick it? (I have a solution if we're allowed to pick a prime $p$ large enough that the DLog problem is hard)

Comment: The polynomials are defined over Zp, which can be a large prime. Can you tell me your solution, please?

Answer (score 4):

My solution is based on [Pedersen commitments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commitment_scheme#A_perfectly_binding_scheme_based_on_the_discrete_log_problem_and_beyond); in this scheme, we work in a prime-sized ($p$) subfield of some group, perhaps $\mathbb{Z}_{kp+1}$, so some prime $kp+1$; where both $p$ and $kp+1$ are large enough to make the discrete log problem intractible.  We have two generators of this subgroup $g$ and $h$, and it is important that no one knows the discrete log of $h$ base $g$.

A commitment in this scheme to a value $x_i$ is the value $g^{x_i} h^{r_i}$ for a random value $r_i$; if you want to open the commitment, you reveal $x_i, r_i$.

One of the things that is interesting about this scheme is that it makes it easy to prove linear relationships; for example, if we have committed to $n$ $x_i$ values, issuing the commitments $c_i = g^{x_i} h^{r_i}$, and want to issue a proof that $\sum a_i x_i = b$ for some public constants $a$ and $b$, all we need to do is to proof that we know the value $y$ such that $\prod (c_i)^{a_i}\cdot g^{-b} = h^y$ - the left side can be computed by the verifier, and so a simple Schnorr proof suffices (and, assuming that the prover remembers all the $r_i$ values he used, he can easily compute $y$)

And, I'll assume that the polynomials $B(x), D(x)$ have a known maximum degree $n$; the polynomials $A(x), A'(x)$ have a known maximum degree $m$ (which may be larger).

With this tool in our toolbox (and with the above assumption), it becomes easy.  To commit to $A(x)$, you publish Pedersen commitments to each coefficient individually (and similarly with $A'(x)$ - there is no need to use the same $r_i$ values unless you decide to make the relationship between $A(x), A'(x)$ obvious at the start)

Then, to send $C(x)$ to X (along with a proof that $C(x) = A(x) \bmod B(x)$), well, we have $A(x) = B(x)K(x) + C(x)$ for some polynomial $K(x)$; so you would give $m-n+1$ Pedersen commitments for the coefficients of $K$.  Then, the above equation can be viewed as a series of linear equations between $A(x)$ and $K(x)$ (and the public to X polynomials $B(x), C(x)$.  So, we just issue $m+1$ proofs that each individual coefficient of $B(x)K(x) + C(x)$ matches $A(x)$.

The last step is to issue a proof that $A(x) = A'(x)$; that is easily done, as that is just another linear relationship, and so the same tool can do it.

QED

Comment: Thank you so much :) I'll have to digest it better, but I think this is exactly what i need. Almost 100k of reputation, you are a crypto god! Can't imagine how many people you already helped.

Comment: Can't you just send individual commitments ci=g^xi of A(X) and K(x) to X? He can commit ci = g^xi of C(x) and B(x) and check that every commitment of A(x) is equal to every commitment of B(x)K(x) + C(x). @poncho

Comment: @Fiono: X cannot compare commitments.  That is, commitments are randomized (they have to be, otherwise they wouldn't be hiding), and so X cannot tell if two different commitments are to the same value.  To do so, he needs some help from the entity that issued the commitments.

Comment: Is it possible to make only one commitment to A(x) and another commitment to K(x) and one proof that A(x) = B(x) * K(x) + C(x) instead of multiple ones? Like commit to a weighted sum of the coefficients of the polynomial. @poncho

Comment: @Fiono: no, it's not possible with Pedersen commitments (actually, it is possible; you can come up with a zero knowledge proof of any statement within NP - it's certainly not easy).  It might be easier with other commitment schemes.

Comment: Is it possible to use the scheme on this paper for this purpose? https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/31eb/add7a0109a584cfbf94b3afaa3c117c78c91.pdf. The idea is that the prover commits to $A(x)$ and $K(x)$ and, after, the verifier asks the prover for $A(y)$ and $K(y)$, $y \in [0, p-1]$. Then, the verifier checks that $A(y) = B(y) * K(y) + C(y)$. @poncho

Comment: @Fiono: hmmmm, would the verifier know the value of $y$?  If so, that leaks information about $A, K$ (run this $deg(A)+1$ times, and you can recover $A$).  If it doesn't, well, it still leaks a small amount of information (e.g. a specific value is a possible value of the polynomial), but in any case, how can the verifier evaluate $B(y), C(y)$?

Comment: the verifier knows $B(x)$ and $C(x)$, so he can calculate $B(y)$ and $C(y)$. The verifier knows the value of $y$ as well, but the prover will only give one point evaluation. Is this enough for the verifier to be convinced that $A(x) = B(x) * K(x) + C(x)$ and that the prover didn't use some other $A'(x)$ to calculate $C(x)$.

Comment: @Fiono: well, that would work (assuming that the field is large enough, and that the prover can't select $y$).  On the other hand, the relation $A(y) = B(y)K(y) + C(y)$ (for public $B, C, y$) is a linear equation; the prover could, given $y$, generate a single ZKP of that; that would leak no information, and would also be more efficient (no pairing operations required).